# I can't delete folders inside WSL which I accidentally created through Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL with a directory `~/library` created within WSL. Then I ran VSCode and opened this folder directly from Windows Explorer, causing to open it as a "local Windows" folder instead of WSL. Adding to the offense, I created 2 folders from VSCode (let's say `foo` and `bar`) inside `library`.

The cost of doing this is that now I can't delete these folders, either from Windows Explorer or WSL (`sudo rmdir foo` or `sudo rm -rf foo`). In Windows and Ubuntu I'm getting access denied errors. I am both Windows admin and root user.

Would be any workaround for removing them?

Comment: To clarify, instead of being "root" user I have sudo permissions.

Comment: Try to reboot your device and delete the content of the directory at first.

Comment: @dan1st yep, this worked. I had to reboot the VM and the host as well

Comment: I ran into this issue and it turns out that I couldn't remove it through the windows explorer either. The reason was, that I was accessing the folder through a programm (Visual Studio Code), thus preventing me from deleting it. Closing the progarmm made me be able to delete it.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe a little too late but to remove folder in your wsl just open your wsl/ubuntu terminal. `cd /`to get to your root. `ls` to find where you created the folder, in my case it was in: `home/user/projects folder`, `cd home/user/projects`. Type this command: `rm -r folder-name`, then `ls` to verify that the folder has been remove.

Comment: Note that the original question specifically stated that they tried this with  `sudo rm -rf foo`.  The comments show that this was an issue that was simply solved via a reboot (locked file/directory).